# How to force http of a single page instead of https in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am forcing https on all pages in my website with this code in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

However I have a page videos.php which I do not want the https on, I want it to be the normal http, how do I do this? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `.htaccess` to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^videos.php - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This will check for urls ending with `videos.php` and will not do anything for those urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# force HTTPS for all pages except videos.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^videos\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# force HTTP for all pages except videos.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^videos\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```